# Pytest hides some parameters values

Tags: python, pytest

when running pytest, I can see each test with its parameters values. eg:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [1])
def test_foo(a):
    pass
```

On terminal I can see the value 1:

```
plugins: metadata-1.8.0, timeout-1.3.3, html-2.0.1
collected 1 item                                                               
<Module a_tests.py>
  <Function test_foo[1]>
```

The problem is, that on more complicated value types (like list) pytest hides the value:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [[1,2,3]])
def test_foo(a):
    pass
```

```
plugins: metadata-1.8.0, timeout-1.3.3, html-2.0.1
collected 1 item                                                               
<Module a_tests.py>
  <Function test_foo[a0]>
```

How can I see the values of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ids` argument to customize the name of parameterized test functions.
The easiest way in your example is just to use `str` to get a string representation of the parameter:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6]], ids=str)
def test_foo(a):
    pass
```

This gives:

```
test.py::test_foo[[1, 2, 3]] 
test.py::test_foo[[4, 5, 6]]
```

For more complicated names you can use a function that takes the parameter as argument. Here is a simple example:

```py
def param_name(param):
    if isinstance(param, list):
        return '-'.join([str(el) for el in param])
    return str(param)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], ids=param_name)
def test_foo(a):
    pass
```

This gives:

```
test.py::test_foo[1-2-3] 
test.py::test_foo[4-5-6]
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Pycharm or another IDE for a more user friendly printing of pytest results.

Comment: "take a look at another IDE" is a very vague advice. Could you show some output or at least name the IDE that really solves the problem?

Comment: Note that an IDE usually doesn't change the test names generated by pytest, it just may format the output differently. PyCharm for example uses something that is similar (not the same) as the output of `pytest -rA`.